Почему нормативным считается только глагол "поскользнуться"?
Мнение
Правильный вариант – поскользнуться. В словарях во всех значениях допускается использование лишь этого глагола с приставкой ПО-. Глагол подскользнуться является просторечным, и его не рекомендуется использовать. Однако некоторые известные авторы всё же писали неправильно.
Вот даже так! Но  вот еще мнение пользователя:
Ну почему, почему в русском языке есть такие слова, как «подсказать» и «подъехать», но нет слова «подскольнуться»?! Хотя «поскользнулся» даже невозможно выговорить!
Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией Т. Ф. Ефремовой
ПОДСКОЛЬЗНУТЬСЯ 
сов. разг. То же, что: поскользнуться.

Грамотным человеком следует считать не только того, кто знает норму, но того, кто может объяснить правило. Иначе это уже не грамотность, а вынужденное послушание.
Так как же можно объяснить значение приставки ПО как единственно правильной?
Обсуждение темы на форуме

Я считаю, что дело в разных семантических оттенках слов поскользнуться и подскользнуться. Поэтому было бы разумным считать основным вариант поскользнуться и разговорным — подскользнуться, как в словаре Ефремовой.
Соответственно, следует исключить это слово из школьных экзаменов, как имеющее варианты письма.
Миниатюра
Поскользнуться или подскользнуться?
— Я кинулся со всех ног, подскользнулся на 
проклятом паркете, однако ж удержался…
— Подскользнулся? Это неграмотно!
— Это Гоголь, Записки сумасшедшего (1835).
— Это раньше так писали, а сейчас норма 
изменилась. Теперь только  глагол «поскользнуться»  
считается правильным.
— Ну тогда  Бродский: Подскользнувшись о вишнёвую 
косточку,  я не падаю…
—  Авторское решение…
— Не авторское.  Он же не падает.  Сравните: 
Поскользнувшись о вишнёвую  косточку,  я падаю…
—  Так правильно!
— Да, правильно.  Есть два разных глагола. 
Поскользнулся, упал. И подскользнулся, однако 
удержался (без полного скольжения).
 — К чему такие тонкости!
 — Действительно…  Но считать  всех неграмотными 
тоже ни к чему.

Забавный стих.
Иосиф Бродский, "Старение" (1972)
          Птица уже не влетает в форточку.
        Девица, как зверь, защищает кофточку.
        Подскользнувшись о вишнёвую косточку,
             я не падаю: сила трения
         возрастает с паденьем скорости.
       Сердце скачет, как белка, в хворосте
         рёбер. И горло поёт о возрасте.
              Это — уже старение.

Кстати,  И. Бродскому здесь 32 года
Статья по теме
